# can unix or utc time in momentjs be rounded to nearest minute?

Tags: unix, timestamp, momentjs, utc

I want to run a cron job every 5 minutes that will process an array associated with a timestamp for example:

5:30pm(in utc/unix) -> [a,b,c]

utc and unix give timestamps rounded to milliseconds and seconds but i need sth rounded to nearest minute. Is that possible and what are my options?

Thanks.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then update your Q. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you're asking.  What kind of input do you have, and what kind of output are you expecting?  Please show an example.